# Javascript / jQuery flick between two images

Tags: javascript, jquery

I'm struggling with the timer part.  I can replace one image with another easily with javascript by calling the function.  What I want to be able to do is set a timer to sit and change the images at a specific interval (say 1 second).

I've used jQuery to refresh an image every second before, but when I try and add a function inside to change the image, it just hangs.

Comment: It would be easier to help, if you show us some code.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

you can use setinterval function of javascript:

```
 setInterval(function,time); //ex: setInterval(myfunction,1000)
```

setInterval will also return a pointer to time which can be used later on to clearInterval

```
var interval = setInterval(myfunction,1000);
```

later  you can use:

```
clearInterval(interval)
```

Comment: That was the next question (cancelling it).  I've got it working (the reason it wasn't was due to the fact that I didn't put quotes round the function.